# Is there a global setting in Chart.js for beginAtZero?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I know i can set the options for each chart like:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I'm using alot of charts and would like ALL chart's yaxis to start at zero as default.

I'm using Chart.js 2.3.0.

Comment: Sorry but I'm on holiday so I haven't been able to test it yet. I will test it next week. :)

Comment: ohk... no worries :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a global setting for `beginAtZero` in ChartJS and you can set it in the follwing way to make all chart's `yAxes` to start at zero ...

```
Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero = true; //set this at the beginning of your code
```

here's a little example ...

```js
Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero = true;

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart1").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [5, 6, 7, 8],
        datasets: [{
      label: "chart # 1",
            data: [5, 6, 7, 8],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.3)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("chart2").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [9, 10, 11, 12],
        datasets: [{
      label: "chart # 2",
            data: [9, 10, 11, 12],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.3)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
<canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't find this in the documentation though... or can I?

Comment: @ConnyOlsson, looks like the docs point to a different approach (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/index.html#updating-axis-defaults)